# quick guide to understand theory of computation

Tags: reference-request, computability

Can someone tell me some quick guides in understanding theory of computation. I know this is not the place to ask such question

Comment: http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/TheoryOfComputation/TheoryOfComputation.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you'd really like to *understand* the theory of computation, then it's best to start with a standard text in the field.

To this end, I suggest you take a look at Michael Sipser's [*Introduction to the Theory of Computation*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/113318779X).

Sipser's text is on the pricey side; there are somewhat shorter notes on the [theory of computation](http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/TheoryOfComputation/TheoryOfComputation.pdf) available in pdf, and freely accessible for downloading.

There are even more condensed [lecture notes](http://csustan.csustan.edu/~tom/Lecture-Notes/Computation/computation.pdf) at the given link, also freely available to download in pdf format.

Disclaimer: "Quick guides" are for reference, as a summary, and/or reviewing previous learning, while some guides may be designed to give you a general overview of a topic. But such guides are likely NOT suitable if your goal is to learn, understand, and master the material you'd learn, say, in an introductory course or two (upper level graduate, say).

Comment: Nice book! Did you see the $$$, ouch! +1